# Override with inherited class as parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I'm working on a modular Weaponsystem for my 2D Game and im kinda stuck with the following Problem:

Lets say i have a abstract base class named `Weapon`

```cs
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage { get; set; }
    public int durablity { get; set; }
    public Sprite sprite { get; set; }

    public abstract void Initialize(WeaponData weaponData);
}
```

and a `Pistol` class which inherit from `Weapon`

```cs
public class Pistol : Weapon {
    PistolData pistolData;

    void Start() {
        Initialize(pistolData);
    }

    public override void Initialize(PistolData pistolData) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

like you can see these two classes use the following two classes in the Initialize Method/Function. A `WeaponData` Class:

```cs
public abstract class WeaponData : ScriptableObject
{
    public int durability;
    public int damage;
}
```

and a `PistolData` which inherit from `WeaponData`

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "new PistolData", menuName = "MyAssets/PistolData", order = 0)]
public class PistolData : WeaponData
{
    public Vector2 pivotPoint;
    public Vector2 firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletForce;
    public Sprite weaponSprite;
    public float fireRate;
}
```

My Problem now: i get an Error because Initialize needs a `WeaponData` and not a `PistolData`. I thought this would work since `PistolData` is practically a `WeaponData` through the inheritance.. at least i thought so..

Is there any way to make this kind of inheritance possible? If not, how should i solve it instead?

Im very new to Unity and C# and i have no Idea left how i could Manage my Weapon System if not like this.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve through defining the abstract base method? If it is only called via the subclass constructor, it is superfluous.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay i only call the Initialize() of the base class. which Initialize() gets used depends of the sub class my weapon is from(e.g. pistol, sword, axe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generics and generic constraints should give you what you need here

```
public abstract class Weapon<TWeaponData> : MonoBehaviour
    where TWeaponData : WeaponData
{
    public int damage { get; set; }
    public int durablity { get; set; }
    public Sprite sprite { get; set; }

    public abstract void Initialize(TWeaponData weaponData);
}
```

Then your pistol class can do this

```
public class Pistol : Weapon<PistolData>
{
    PistolData pistolData;

    void Start() {
        Initialize(pistolData);
    }

    public override void Initialize(PistolData pistolData) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what i was looking for. worked like a charm. perfect. Thank you. I only knew generics from Java. I never saw them in use for c#

Comment: C# has a much deeper and more powerful implementation of generics that Java, its worth doing a bit of research on, just so you know the differences

Comment: is there any way now to initialize a `Weapon<> weapon` as Pistol or another weapon subclass? something like `Weapon<WeaponData> = new Pistol()`? Because my HandleWeapon-Script only has a Weapon on it since this can be all types of weapon

Comment: ah you've moved into the world of covariance and contravariance. The quick answer  (I think) is no, if you had an interface IWeapon then you can use the in and out keywords for the generic arg, ie IWeapon<out TWeaponData> or IWeapon<in TWeaponData> - however this isnt a simple matter that can be answered in a comment. Have a good of covariance/contravariance in c# and it should guide you on your way

Answer (score 2):

You could make the method parameterless and simply use the values fromt he field

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    // do something with pistolData since you seem to have it as field
}
```

---

You could also add a type check like

```
public class Pistol : Weapon 
{
    [SerializeField] PistolData _pistolData;

    void Start() 
    {
        Initialize(pistolData);
    }

    public override void Initialize(WeaponData weaponData)
    {
        if (!(weaponData is PistolData pistolData))
        {
            Debug.LogError("I expected a " + nameof(PistolData), this);
            return;
        }

        // use pistolData
    }
}
```

---

Or you could rather implement in `Weapon` what the weapon should do and use non-override methods in your inherited ones:

```
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage { get; private set; }
    public int durablity { get; private set; }
    public Sprite sprite { get; set; }

    protected void Initialize(WeaponData weaponData)
    {
        damage = weapondData.damage;
        durability = weaponData.durability
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Pistol : Weapon
{
    public void Initialize(PistolData pistolData)
    {
        base.Initialize(pistolData);

        // do pistol specific stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: While this would compile it's a very poor design. Why have an abstract base method in the first place if your checking the argument type in the subclass?

Comment: There are a lot of cases where you want to do so. Do you have a better design then provide it as alternative ;)

Comment: There isn't enough context in the question to provide a proper solution. However, you shouldn't need to remember which specific sub type to pass to a method, then find out any mistakes at runtime.

Comment: I'm afraid you got me wrong. I dont want to check if the argument is a PistolData or not. i want to use the Initialize() Method with different WeaponData subclasses. like PistolData or SwordData.. but unfortunately in my Visual Studio it says: Initialize MUST use WeaponData. not its childs

Comment: @Cratuss well and exactly that isn't possible unless you use alternatives as I provided or search for others ;) If you `override` the method you may not change its signature

Comment: @derHugo now that you edited your answer it makes much more sense. But the problem is still the same. you use ```base.Initialize(pistolData)``` but i get an error by that because pistolData is no `WeaponData` do you have another way maybe? Anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: For the last `public void Initialize(PistolData pistolData)
        {
            base.Initialize(pistolData);
        }` works for me and does not throw any error. `PistolData` **is** a `WeaponData`